# Is there a fast and efficient way to multiply an Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to be able to get from `[2, 3]` and `3 : [2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]`.
(Like `3 * a` in python where a is a list)

Is there a quick and efficient way to do this in Javascript ?
I do this with a `for` loop, but it lacks visibility and I guess efficiency.

I would like for it to work with every types of element.

For instance, I used the code :

```
function dup (n, obj) {
var ret = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = obj;
    }
    return (ret);
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work with arrays or objects, only with primitive values.

Do I have to make conditions, or is there a clean way to duplicate a variable ?

Comment: I don't understand how a loop "lacks visibility and efficiency".

Comment: Better description please. I don't really get your issue if for loop is inefficient. And I am not such a python pro.

Comment: If you want to multiple all entries by the same number you can use `array.prototype.map`, if you want them multiplied all together use `array.prototype.reduce`. However using a loop in JavaScript is actually the fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this (very readable :P) function:

```
function repeat(arr, n){
  var a = [];
  for (var i=0;i<n;[i++].push.apply(a,arr));
  return a;
}
```

`repeat([2,3], 3)` returns an array `[2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]`.

Basically, it's this:

```
function repeat(array, times){
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i=0; i < times; i++){
    Array.prototype.push.apply(newArray, array);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

we push `array`'s values onto `newArray` `times` times. To be able to push an array as its values (so, `push(2, 3)` instead of `push([2, 3])`) I used apply, which takes an array an passes it to push as a list of arguments.

Or, extend the prototype:

```
Array.prototype.repeat = function(n){
  var a = [];
  for (var i=0;i<n;[i++].push.apply(a,this));
  return a;
}
```

`[2, 3].repeat(3)` returns an array `[2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]`.

If you want something reasonably readable, you can use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) within a loop:

```
function repeat(array, n){
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    newArray = newArray.concat(array);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: his way lacks visibility. your way is hidden. xD

Comment: it's not about name.`[i++].push.apply(a,this)` is very complex.you can do it like `a = a.concat(arr)` inside the loop.maybe it will be visible xD

Comment: `push.apply` allows you to concatenate without the creation of a new variable tho.

Comment: @OmarElawady That's cool! I didn't know about `.concat`! Thanks, I'll use it to clarify my answer :)

Comment: @Andy the idea is that `[i++].push.apply(a,this)` is hard to understand.if push is better he can do it `Array.prototype.push.apply(a, this)`.they're the same but I think the second is clearer.

Answer (score -2):

There is not.   This is a very Pythonic idea.

You could devise a function to do it, but I doubt there is any computational benefit because you would just be using a loop or some weird misuse of string functions.

Comment: The question is about JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the PHP reference.  I got confused :P

Comment: it not works if array like [23,23]

Comment: You should be returning integers, not strings.

Comment: Like I said it was weird, and I was not recommending that piece of code nor do I wish to perfect it.  It was just an example of how join() and split() can be used to generate an array without using a loop.   I have removed it as it seems it was drawing negative attention.